# Excel, how to only sum cells with a numeric value

Tags: worksheet-function

How do I sum a column for its numeric value when there are both numbers and dates in the column?

example:

```
2
12
38
12-Dec
2
1
1
1-Jan
2
1
```

Comment: Does [Sum numbers in a column , exclude date value | MrExcel Message Board](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sum-numbers-in-a-column-exclude-date-value.849849/) answer your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hmm... trying things in LibreOffice; and failing - I would expect Excel to respond with a sum of "non-dates" for a formula similar to this: `=( (TYPE(A1:A10))=1 )*A1:A10` entered as an array formula (type formula, then do Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: @Hannu Dates will return 1 as Excel considers them as numbers.